# Spring "webflux oauth2 resource server" with anonymous endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, anonymous

i'm using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server 2.3.6.RELEASE.
As described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#webflux-oauth2-resource-server) the security config has to be done by providing:

```
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
            .pathMatchers("/message/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_message:read")
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
            .jwt(withDefaults())
        );
    return http.build();
}
```

Does anybody has an idea, how to add a "public" endpoint in the resource server, that is accessible ba an anonymous user?

Thanks Fredy

--- update 17.2.2021 8:43 ---
I changed the code as suggested, but still get a Access Denied.
In org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot
Line 111 -> `isAuthenticated()` is returning false. That's correct, but for me just not so great.

```
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
            .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                    .pathMatchers("/init").permitAll()
                    .pathMatchers("/message/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_message:read")
                    .anyExchange().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(withDefaults()));
    return http.build();
}
```

Log:

```
2021-02-17 08:33:11 DEBUG [http-nio-8082-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy [FilterChainProxy.java:328] /error at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2021-02-17 08:33:11 DEBUG [http-nio-8082-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy [FilterChainProxy.java:328] /error at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2021-02-17 08:33:11 DEBUG [http-nio-8082-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor [AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:219] Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /error; Attributes: [authenticated]
2021-02-17 08:33:11 DEBUG [http-nio-8082-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor [AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:348] Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@615c75f9: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@166c8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 1CF0ACC15C790FEA93EF30F39DDC6492; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2021-02-17 08:33:11 DEBUG [http-nio-8082-exec-2] org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased [AffirmativeBased.java:66] Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@4e3ebe19, returned: -1
2021-02-17 08:33:11 DEBUG [http-nio-8082-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter [ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:180] Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
```

Answer (score 0):

A public endpoint is added in the same way that the `/message` endpoint was added:

```java
http
    .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
        .pathMatchers("/my/public/endpoint").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/message/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_message:read")
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
    )
    // ...
```

The path matchers are interpreted one at a time for each request. The rules from the first path match are applied.

Comment: Yes, that is what i also expect, but it doesn't work.
org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot Line 111
isAuthenticated() is returning false. That's correct, but for me just not so great ;-)

How can i add the log here, without everything exploding? I will add a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that the WebSecurityConfig was not in the "scanBasePackages" of  @SpringBootApplication.

Comment: this is wrong, this question is about reactive version of the stack, the configuration class uses the `@EnableWebFluxSecurity` annotation which relies on `WebFluxSecurityConfiguration` and not the `@EnableWebSecurity` which relies on `WebSecurityConfig`, traditional and reactive tools do not work together as said here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53847627/spring-webflux-with-traditional-web-security